# Only display most recently modified record

Tags: apex, visualforce

Im working on a visualforce page for the contact standard object.

1. First I created an custom button and and directed it to a visualforce page
2. I set up the page to display a pop-up once a user enters an email
3. The pop-up displays all records related to that email

Instead of showing all records, I only want to show the most recently modified record.

## Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="TestPopup" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:commandButton value="show popup" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="popup" status="status"/>
                <apex:outputPanel id="popup">
                <apex:outputPanel id="popInnerOutputPnl" styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
                    <apex:commandButton value="X" title="Close the popup" action="{!closePopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
                    </apex:commandButton>
                    <apex:pageblockSection>                         

                        <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Email" for="address"></apex:outputLabel>
                                <apex:inputText value="{!searchstring}" label="Input"/>   
                        </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

                    </apex:pageblockSection>

                    <apex:commandButton value="Ok" action="{!redirectPopup}" styleClass="closeButton" rerender="popup">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!Search}" reRender="popup"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:outputPanel>

            <apex:pageblockTable var="con" value="{!contact}">
                <apex:column value="{!con.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!con.LastName}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!con.Email}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!con.Account.Name}"/>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

    <style type="text/css">
        .customPopup {
            background-color: white;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 2px;
            left: 20%;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 9999;
            /* These are the 3 css properties you will need to tweak so the pop 
                                    up displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set 
                                    margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can also add 
                                    the height property for a fixed size pop up.*/
            width: 500px;
            top: 20%;
        }

        .disabledTextBox {
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid;
            color: black;
            cursor: default;
            width: 90px;
            display: table;
            padding: 2px 1px;
            text-align:right;
        }   

        .closeButton {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>

</apex:page>
```

## Class:

```
public with sharing class TestPopup {

    public Boolean displayPopup {get;set;}
    public list<contact> contact {get;set;}
    public string searchstring {get;set;}  
    //  public string Email { get; set; }

    public TestPopup(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {}

    public TestPopup () 
    {
        // contact  = new list<Contact>();
    }

    public void showPopup()
    {
        displayPopup = true;
    }

    public void closePopup() 
    {
        displayPopup = false;
    }

    public PageReference redirectPopup()
    {

        displayPopup = false;

        //Please uncomment below 3 statements and replace YourObjectId
        // PageReference p=new Pagereference('/'+YourObjectId);
        // p.setRedirect(true);

        return null;

    }

    public PageReference Search()
    {
        displayPopup = false;

        //searched = true;

        string searchquery='select firstName,LastName,id,Account.Name,email from Contact where email like \'%'+searchstring+'%\' Limit 20';  
        contact= Database.query(searchquery);  

        system.debug('record is---->' +contact);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this inside the `WHERE` clause of your soql query.

```
WHERE Email LIKE \'%'+searchstring+'%\' ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

Set the limit to one to return just the top record, and then set the [`ORDER BY` clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_select_order_by_with_limit.htm) to sort the records by the `LastModifiedDate`. You'll need to specify that the order is `DESC` for descending order, to get the highest date at the top of the returned list, and the oldest date at the bottom.

---

Additionally, if you are new to salesforce development, I would recommend both the [Apex trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trail/force_com_dev_beginner) and the [Visualforce trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/visualforce_fundamentals). They're an excellent way to get accustomed to the platform.